# How to export Firestore when offline persistence is activated?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using Firebase in a ReactJS framework. I have setup a config.js where I initialize Firebase and export my firestore instance and all works fine now:

```
export const store = firebase.firestore();
```

I'm trying to enable offline persistence but how should I export my store variable now?

```
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
  .then(function() {
      // Initialize Cloud Firestore through firebase
      var store = firebase.firestore();
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
      if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
          // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
          // in one tab at a a time.
          // ...
      } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
          // The current browser does not support all of the
          // features required to enable persistence
          // ...
      }
  });
```

I was trying to export the promise but it does not work. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

since they changed the behavior and there is no correct way told to us, i did this:

firestore.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

export var db = firebase.firestore()
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true }
db.settings(settings)


export function initializeDatabase() { 
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        firebase.firestore().enablePersistence({experimentalTabSynchronization:true})
        .then(function() {

            //update the database variable to reflect the one with persistenceEnabled
            db = firebase.firestore();

            resolve()
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
                // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
                // in one tab at a a time.
                // ...
            } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
                // The current browser does not support all of the
                // features required to enable persistence
                // ...
            }

            //Nothing to do, it was previsoly initilaized in the var db 
            resolve()
          });
})
}
```

now in the main.js, you should call the method that initialize the database

main.js:

```
let app;

initializeDatabase().then(function() {
  initializeSecureApp()
})

function initializeSecureApp() {
  if(!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app');

    // defaultListeners()
  }
}
```

ps: im kind of noob, but thats the only way i found that is working to only start the app after the persistence database is setted

ps: sorry if the question is old, but i had this problem today and had to search for it

ps: you can implement reject instead of _ and update the call to the initializeDatabase to handle the error

if someone has a better way, please post here